# Not logging for Google Analytics Tagmanager pushEvent

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Currently i am using Tag manager library to send Statistic of my E Commerce application to Google Analytic -> Enhanced E commerce. As per the acceptance criteria for this functionality to be done, the GAv4 log should be displaying but unfortunately i am  not getting any log, although I've successfully run the commands required to show GAv4 logs from Terminal.

Earlier i was pushing an Event "openScreen" for this event log are displaying successfully but currently i am using different events like "productImpression", "promotionClick". I am not getting any log for these events. Please help me out from this if anybody have a good experience with Google Analytic.

Are these Events in built from the GA or do we need to configure it somewhere on GA dashboard? Is there anything i am missing in code to push events. here below is the code snippet.

Not working Code:-

```
dataLayer.pushEvent("promotionClick",
            DataLayer.mapOf(
                    "ecommerce", DataLayer.mapOf(
                            "promoClick", DataLayer.mapOf(
                                    "promotions", DataLayer.listOf(
                                            DataLayer.mapOf(
                                                    "id", "APRIL_PROMO13",          // Name or ID is required.
                                                    "name", "Spring Sunrise",
                                                    "creative", "banner6",
                                                    "position", "slot6"))))));
```

Working Code:-

```
dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", SCREEN_NAME));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include information on how your Google Analytics tag is setup, and whether you've published it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Later on i resolved this problem by configuring the tag on TagManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to leave an actual answer here:

This is a valid event for ecommerce promo clicks, but the Google Tag Manager container needed to be published, right?